# Run NodeApp in command-like way?

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js

[NodeApp's](http://nodeapp.org/) `NLContext` is able to interpret JS using `evaluateScript`. At the same time it [supports](https://github.com/node-app/Interpreter#whats-working-right-now) `argv` and `env`:

**What's working right now:**

- process: .argv, .env, .exit(), .nextTick()

How to run NodeApp in command-like way and pass command-line arguments? Relates to env. variables too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving in source code i've found the answer: no `argv`s are passed, `env` are passed as `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` (see [NLContext.m](https://github.com/node-app/Nodelike/blob/master/Nodelike/NLContext.m)):

```
JSValue *process = [JSValue valueWithObject:@{
        @"platform": @"darwin",
        @"argv":     @[],
        @"env":      NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment,
        @"execPath": NSBundle.mainBundle.executablePath,
        @"_asyncFlags": @{},
        @"moduleLoadList": @[]
    } inContext:context];
```

To modify them one need to add setters and pass variables before `NLContext.attachToContext` invocation is done.

PS. -1 to karma to 2 'close' voters. Hope my question and answer help somebody